# Can data files be considered software?

Tags: terminology

I 've heard some people refering to data files(by data files i dont mean excecutables,libraries,documentations,conf files but simple text files,audio files,documents etc) as software. I have found some definitions that say that whatever is not hardware is software, although most of them clearly define software as programs,scripts etc. Is it a matter of context and opinion or is there a clear definition.

It may sound like a stupid question and it propably is, but i always when referring to software mean programs and not data files so i want to know if i am wrong.

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software ;)

Comment: I have read it of course :) But the first result in google for "software definition" from webopedia states that **Anything that can be stored electronically is software**. http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/software.html

Comment: Apparently there is no clear definition so I guess it is indeed a matter of context and opinion..

Answer (score 1):

I believe data files would be considered assets or resources, not software by itself, but stuff that the software uses to accomplish its purpose. For example, most of a game's content is assets, such as music, models, textures, cutscenes and that kind of stuff; the actual software is just the game engine and that's it.

That said, I'm not sure if this distinction could apply for legal purposes. I would believe that data files (game assets in my example) could be considered as separate from the software and this is why it is possible to do stuff like OpenTTD, which is a GNU freeware reimplementation of Transport Tycoon Deluxe's game engine originally designed to use its assets, which used to be provided by the player (until someone designed GPL-licensed assets), or like pytouhou which is Touhou Koumakyou's game engine reimplemented in Python but using ZUN's official game assets.